# JavaFX, text won't display in TextArea

Tags: javafx, linked-list, textarea, javafx-8

I have the majority of the program done, the only problem is getting the numbers to display in the `TextArea`. Write a program that lets the user enter numbers from a graphical user interface and displays them in a text area. Use a `LinkedList` to store the numbers. Don't duplicate numbers. Add sort, shuffle, reverse to sort the list.

```
package storedInLinkedList;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;

public class StoredInLinkedList extends Application{

    TextField txt = new TextField();
    TextArea tArea = new TextArea();
    Label message = new Label("Enter a Number: ");
    Button sort = new Button("Sort");
    Button shuffle = new Button("Shuffle");
    Button reverse = new Button("Reverse");
    private LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        BorderPane bPane = new BorderPane();


        txt.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
        bPane.setCenter(txt);
        bPane.setBottom(tArea);

        HBox hBox = new HBox(message, txt);
            bPane.setTop(hBox);

        HBox buttons = new HBox(10);
            buttons.getChildren().addAll(sort, shuffle, reverse);
        bPane.setBottom(buttons);
            buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
            vBox.getChildren().addAll(hBox, tArea, buttons);

        bPane.setCenter(new ScrollPane(tArea));

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 300,250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("20.2_DSemmes");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        txt.setOnAction(e -> {
            if(! list.contains(new Integer(txt.getText()))){
                tArea.appendText(txt.getText() + " ");
                list.add(new Integer(txt.getText()));
            }//end if
        });//end action

        sort.setOnAction(e -> {
            Collections.sort(list);
            display();
        });//end action

        shuffle.setOnAction(e -> {
            Collections.shuffle(list);
            display();
        });//end action

        reverse.setOnAction(e -> {
            Collections.reverse(list);
            display();
        });//end action

    }//end stage 

    private void display() {

        for (Integer i: list){
            tArea.setText(null);
            tArea.appendText(i + " ");
        }//end for 
    }//end display

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        launch(args);
    }//end main

}//end class
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the textarea clearing code outside of for loop. Otherwise you are clearing the previously appended text, so textarea having only the last element of `list`:

```
private void display() {
    tArea.setText("");  // clear text area
    for (Integer i: list){
        tArea.appendText(i + " ");
    }//end for 
}/
```